# AWS url request

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have no odea what is wrong with this request ??

`http://ecs.amazonaws.de/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIGPEW5&AssociateTag=dualda0e-20&Keywords=s.Oliver%20Herren%20Kapuzenpullover%2013.402.31.5523%2C%20Einfarbig%2C%20Gr.%20X-Large%2C%20Gr%C3%BCn&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Images%2CItemAttributes%2CItemIds%2C%20EditorialReview%2CReviews%2CSimilarities&SearchIndex=All&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2014-09-13T05%3A39%3A50Z&Version=2010-10-01®ion=de&Signature=YzEMNGCNSlRGKHvfECpZdXpXagpm61bLDq21ByRwUI8%3D`

(i changed access key)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `®` is a pretty big clue there. It probably needs to be `&region=de` not `®ion=de`. (I've checked the raw text of your question to make sure it wasn't just a rendering thing here on SO.)

Somewhere along the line, you're putting that URL somewhere where it's being interpreted as HTML, and then the interpreted version is being used. Since `&region` looks like a slightly mis-typed `&reg;ion`, browsers will go ahead and render it as `®ion`.

Wherever it is you're outputting that to HTML, ensure that you correctly encode your ampersands as `&amp;` to avoid this sort of thing.